# PayPal Pay Button Implementation with React and Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using Laravel for backend and React for frontend (very new to both) and I'm trying to implement a purchase button that works with PayPal (Omnipay). However, when I click the pay button I get a bunch of errors:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFttG.png)

This is part of what I have on my frontend.

```
export default function OnePost({ postP }) {
    const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
        amount: "",
    });

    const pay = (e, value) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setData({ amount: value });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data.amount !== "") {
            post(route("payment", [data.amount]));
        }
    }, [data.amount]);
    return (
            ... 
                    <div className="">
                        {" "}
                        <form
                            onSubmit={(e) => pay(e, postP.price)}
                            encType="multipart/form-data"
                        >
                            <input
                                type="hidden"
                                name="amount"
                                value={postP.price}
                            />
                            {postP.price !== 0 && (
                                <PrimaryButton
                                    type="submit"
                                    disabled={processing}
                                >
                                    Buy for {postP.price}
                                </PrimaryButton>
                            )}
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
    );
}
```

I also have these routes defined on my web.php:

```
Route::post('pay', [PaymentController::class, 'pay'])->name('payment');
Route::get('success', [PaymentController::class, 'success']);
Route::get('error', [PaymentController::class, 'error']);
```

And here is my PaymentController.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Omnipay\Omnipay;
use App\Models\Payment;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    private $gateway;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Rest');
        $this->gateway->setClientId(env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID'));
        $this->gateway->setSecret(env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET'));
        $this->gateway->setTestMode(true);
    }

    public function pay(Request $request)
    {
        try {

            $response = $this->gateway->purchase(array(
                'amount' => $request->amount,
                'currency' => env('PAYPAL_CURRENCY'),
                'returnUrl' => url('success'),
                'cancelUrl' => url('error')
            ))
            ->send();

            if ($response->isRedirect()) {
                // dd($response);
                $response->redirect();
                //send json response back
                
            }
            else{
                return $response->getMessage();
            }

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return $th->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function success(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->input('paymentId') && $request->input('PayerID')) {
            $transaction = $this->gateway->completePurchase(array(
                'payer_id' => $request->input('PayerID'),
                'transactionReference' => $request->input('paymentId')
            ));

            $response = $transaction->send();

            if ($response->isSuccessful()) {

                $arr = $response->getData();

                $payment = new Payment();
                $payment->payment_id = $arr['id'];
                $payment->payer_id = $arr['payer']['payer_info']['payer_id'];
                $payment->payer_email = $arr['payer']['payer_info']['email'];
                $payment->amount = $arr['transactions'][0]['amount']['total'];
                $payment->currency = env('PAYPAL_CURRENCY');
                $payment->payment_status = $arr['state'];

                $payment->save();

                return "Payment is Successfull. Your Transaction Id is : " . $arr['id'];

            }
            else{
                return $response->getMessage();
            }
        }
        else{
            return 'Payment declined!!';
        }
    }

    public function error()
    {
        return 'User declined the payment!';   
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me understand these errors?

I tried looking through Stack Overflow, YouTube, and much else.

Comment: What is the actual behavior of the page? Does it work, or not? Try hosting your site on a domain, not localhost.

Comment: Can you make sure if the route is in actual invoking? because in your console.log it shows 404.

Comment: @KashifUllah Sorry, I am not sure what actual invoking is, I am very new to this. Am I supposed to set up the routes mentioned in the errors? I want user to be able to complete a purchase and be redirected to homepage once transaction is complete.

Comment: @PrestonPHX the page doesn't work. I want users to be able to pay through payPal, but I get the depicted errors when I click buy.

Comment: The problem seems here: post(route("payment", [data.amount]));

Comment: It should be: post(route("pay", [data.amount]));

Comment: @KashifUllah When I change it from payment to pay, it says the route isn't in the route list. It is getting to the backend, but I've figured out that the main issue is the $response->redirect(); in my backend.

Comment: Why are you redirecting to begin with? A backend is used to create and capture orders, yes, but no redirects should be used for current integrations. See the official `@paypal/react-paypal-js` package's examples